# Changing "faire goûter quelque chose à quelqu'un"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

> - J’ai préparé un repas improvisé, et je serais ravi de **le faire goûter à l’homme** dont tu parles.

---

I'm confused by how I should change this phrase in bold if the sentence uses the pronoun "le" instead of "l’homme dont tu parles". In this case, I will then have two "le"s, one for "repas" and the other for "l'homme".

> - Problem 1: J’ai préparé un repas improvisé, et je serais ravi de **le le faire goûter**.

---

Also, what if I don't use any pronoun? Is such a long phrase as below easy to understand for native speakers?

> - Problem 2: Je serais ravi de **faire goûter à ce repas à l’homme** dont tu parles.

Comment: Even if there's not already a *le*, the right pronoun for "*l'homme*" here is *lui* : "*Faire goûter mon plat* ***à l'homme***" = "***Lui*** *faire goûter mon plat*". (Also it would be the same with *la femme* here. When used like this, *lui* goes used for both genders).

Answer (score 3):

In the following sentence

> J’ai préparé un repas improvisé, et je serais ravi de le faire goûter à l’homme dont tu parles.

**le** is used as a pronoun for **un repas improvisé**

If you want to replace the part **à l'homme dont tu parles** by a pronoun you should use **lui** (masculin)

The full sentence would look like

> J’ai préparé un repas improvisé, et je serais ravi de le lui faire goûter.

---

Without pronouns, it will look like

> Je serais ravi de faire goûter ce repas à l’homme dont tu parles.

You were close. You don't need to use **à ce repas** but only **ce repas**

The verb **faire goûter** is used like **faire goûter quelque chose** and **faire goûter à quelqu'un**

Answer (score 0):

Weedoze's answer is correct.

To chose between **le/la** and **lui**, you have to understand the function of the word in the sentence.

If the word is **COD** (*Complément d'Objet Direct*), it will be replaced by **le/la**

> *I'm eating an apple* - Je mange une pomme. -> Je la mange.

If the word is **COI** (*Complément d'Objet Indirect*), it will be replaced by **lui**

> *I'm talking **to** a friend* - Je parle **à** un ami. -> Je lui parle.

To find differences between COD and COI, the presence of **to** in english (**à** in french) before the word tells it's a COI.